# q-btn click event not working on q-checkbox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

There is a `q-checkbox` inside the `q-btn`. I also added a `div` because I want to add some style to the text.

```
<q-btn
      flat
      color="blue"
      class="full-width no-padding"
      @click="tog(item)"
    >
      <q-checkbox
        class="q-mr-sm"
        v-model="item.toggle"
      />

      <div class="text-caption text-grey" style="">{{ item.label }}</div>
      <q-space />
    </q-btn>
```

When I click on the text, the `tog(item)` function fires and works well, but when I click on the checkbox itself nothing happens. Is there any way to fire the `tog()` function when the checkbox is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this code.

```
<q-btn color="white" text-color="black" label="Standard"  @click.stop="tog()">
      
       <q-checkbox
        class="q-mr-sm"
        v-model="item.toggle"
      />

      <div class="text-caption text-grey" style="">{{ item.label }}</div>
      <q-space />
    </q-btn>

const { ref } = Vue

const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup () {
    return {
      item: ref({toggle: false, label: 'aaa'})
    }
  },
  methods:{
    tog(){
      this.item.toggle = !this.item.toggle
    }
  }
})

app.use(Quasar, { config: {} })
app.mount('#q-app')
```

Codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/zYjEENr